# How to install rtorrent on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: software-installation, rtorrent

I have newly installed Ubuntu Server 12.04 and I want to use rtorrent. How can I install it?

Comment: http://blog.walakka.com/2010/07/20/installing-rtorrent-rutorrent-on-ubuntu-server-10-04-lts/

Comment: I have followed step by step in this tutorial, everything is describe, how to install and configure ruTorrent and rtorrent on Ubuntu. http://terminal28.com/how-to-install-and-configure-rutorrent-rtorrent-libtorrent-xmlrpc-screen-ubuntu/

Answer (score 4):

You should just run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtorrent
```

from the console.

Answer (score 1):

To use rtorrent in Ubuntu 12.04, simply install the [rtorrent [image: Install rtorrent]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/rtorrent) package in the Software Center.

(However, if you have a command-line only system without the Software Center, you should use [this way](https://askubuntu.com/a/134259/22949). You may want to accept *that* answer.)